# Why does sleep, when run in a shell script, ignore SIGINT?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sleep, sigint

When I run `sleep` manually, and then `kill -INT` it, sleep exits immediately.  For example:

```
$  /bin/sleep  60  &
[1] 4002356
$  kill -INT 4002356
[1]+  Interrupt               /bin/sleep 60
$  ps -C sleep
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
$
```

However, when I do the same thing in a shell script, `sleep` ignores the `SIGINT`.  For example:

```
set  -o xtrace

echo
/bin/sleep  10  &
child="$!"
/bin/sleep  0.1
ps -C sleep
kill  -TERM  "$child"    #  SIGTERM                                         
/bin/sleep  0.1
ps -C sleep
wait  "$child"    #  will return immediately                                

echo
/bin/sleep  10  &
child="$!"
/bin/sleep  0.1
ps -C sleep
kill  -INT  "$child"    #  SIGINT
/bin/sleep  0.1
ps -C sleep
wait  "$child"    #  will wait for 9.8 seconds
```

Why/how does sleep ignore `SIGINT` when I run `sleep` inside a shell script?

I get the same behavior with `dash` and `bash`.  My kernel is Linux 5.4.0.

Comment: Because of the "&" it is not running "in" the script, but in background, and that may be the reason.

Comment: Observations: (1) `set +m` seems very relevant. Try with `set -m` and compare. (2) In my Debian the phenomenon does not occur in `posh`; this shell does not support `set -m`/`set +m`.

Comment: I confirm that with `dash -m`, `sleep` exits upon receiving SIGINT, as expected.  I'm reading your answer now, and pondering how a child process can inherit a signal handler *across* an exec().  I was not aware that was possible.

Comment: @mpb A signal *handler* doesn't persist across exec(), but the ignored/not-ignored status does. More precisely, if a signal has a handler, exec() resets it to the default action, which is to kill the process for many but not all signals (e.g. SIGTSTP, SIGCONT).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `/bin/sleep 10 &` the terminating `&` makes the shell run `sleep` asynchronously. Job control is by default disabled in a script. In Bash the following applies [emphasis mine]:

> Non-builtin commands started by Bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited by the shell from its parent. **When job control is not in effect, asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT** and SIGQUIT in addition to these inherited handlers.

<sup>Source: [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html#Signals).</sup>

And relatedly, `SIG_IGN` persists across a call to `execv()`, with the possible exception of `SIGCHLD`.

> Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image. Except for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image. Signals set to be caught by the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image (see <signal.h>).

<sup>Source: [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).</sup>